# Error creating Visio object: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed due to the following error: 80080005."

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

So I have an application that is converting different Office file types to pdf, and one of the file types is Visio. I'm also doing Excel and Word Doc files, which are working correctly.

I get the error on this line:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application visApp = 
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();
```

I have 32-bit Office installed on my 32-bit server, including Visio.

I was getting a similar error with my Word and Excel files, and I needed to do some DCOM security configuration by going to `Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config`, and adding permissions for Microsoft Excel Application and Microsoft Word 97-2003 Document. I changed the permissions for Microsoft Visio Drawing, but that didn't fix it.

I'm not sure what else I need to check for, anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: What's the CLSID in the error?  Did you do a web search for that CLSID?

Comment: Was the error generated after a lengthy pause in execution of the application, or did it except immediately? One cause of this error can be the lapsing of a 120-sec timeout for the COM class factory to be registered...

Comment: @DStanley - the CLSID is 00021A20-0000-0000-C000-000000000046

Comment: @DavidW - I thought it was occurring immediately, but I've been checking again now, and the error comes after a long execution. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: @Steven - If the CPU on which your app is running is stressed it can cause this problem, stalling on the call to CoCreateInstance after 120 seconds. It *might* also imply an "under the hood" problem with the installation of Visio, but that's a stretch. There's a good general explanation of this issue (and other possible causes) at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/06/24/432519.aspx

Comment: @DavidW - thanks, I'll take a look at that. In the meantime, I'm moving the application to its own server, maybe that will solve the issue.